# How to use findOne() in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have node.js code and I use mongoose. I don't get any error, just `Successfuly logged in`.

I'm trying to solve this problem couple of days, I have tried lot of things but none of them worked.

This is the server code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const model = require('.//models/schema');

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/register', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/html/register.html');
});

app.get('/login', function(request, response){
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/html/login.html')
});

const listener = app.listen(3000, function() {
  let myURL = new URL(`localhost:${listener.address().port}/register`);
  console.log(myURL.href);
});

mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost${listener.address().port}:/register`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true    
    });

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
 }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/submit-data', async (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/login')
  try {
    const newUser = new model({
      'login': req.body.login,
      'password': req.body.password,
      'gender': req.body.gender,
      'birthday': req.body.birthday
    });

    await newUser.save();
    console.log('User registered');
  } catch {
    console.log('Registeration failed')
  }
});

app.post('/submit-login', (req, res) => {
  const user = model.findOne({
    'login': req.body.login,
    'password': req.body.password,
  });
  if (!user) {
    console.log('Login failed');
  } else {
    console.log('Successfully logged in')
  }
});
```

And this is the model code:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let schema = new Schema({
    'login': String,
    'password': String,
    'gender': String,
    'birthday': String
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('allInfo', schema);
```

I expected it to print 'Login failed' if it is not the same password or login and 'Successfully logged in' if the password and the login are the same.

Comment: Because your if statement is always truthy `if (!user)`. User is true because an object with key value pairs is truthy e.i. : it will resolve to true. Even an empty object is truthy: `let user = {}; console.log(!!user);`

Comment: @Michelangelo when there are no matches, mongoose.findOne will return `null` so the if condition is not always truthy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)

You should move the condition to the callback, like this:

```
const user = model.findOne({
  'login': req.body.login,
  'password': req.body.password,
}, function (err, user) {
  if (!user) {
    console.log('Login failed');
  } else {
    console.log('Successfully logged in')
  }
}));
```

### Update

Also one thing to note, from [mongoose.model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#compiling)  Docs

> The first argument is the singular name of the collection your model is for. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural, lowercased version of your model name.

This means in your code, the model will be looking for a collection called `allinfos`, if your table in the database is called `users` then you should change this line

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('allInfo', schema);
```

To this:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema); // This will look-up the collection users
```

Comment: @CheapsiT Can you log the result of user?

Comment: @CheapsiT I have added something to note, maybe this is the confusion you're having, if it still doesn't solve it, please provide us with the error message or more info to help you debug this, for example: `console.log(user)` like @Michelangelo suggested